# Notification without vibration

Tags: notifications, vibration, outlook

I'd like to have notifications for Outlook for Android to appear in the notification bar, but not get vibrations every time a new email is received.  How can I do that?

Comment: You can try my answer: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/181184/96277

Answer (score 2):

From your Outlook inbox, go to your settings (gear icon in the top right) and select "Notifications". There should be an option to disable vibration there:

[image: screenshot of vibrate setting]

Comment: This disabled the flashing LED. Not useful.

Comment: Doesn't disable the LED on my phone and that wasn't a consideration in the question anyway ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯